# The Difference Between Hierarchical and Non-Hierarchical Taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy, tags, hierarchical

The question is ***"What is the Difference Between Hierarchical and Non-Hierarchical Taxonomies?"*** This question really stumped me at first so I figured it would be a good idea to show the difference to others surfing the site looking for the distinction.

Specifically the question is referring to the `hierarchical` argument passed to the `register_taxonomy()` function. More specifically, what's the difference between this:

### 'hierarchical'    => false

```
register_taxonomy('movie-genre', 'movie', array(
  'hierarchical'    => false,
  'label'           => 'Genre',
  'query_var'       => 'movie-genre',
  'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'genres' ),
));
```

And this?

### 'hierarchical'    => true

```
register_taxonomy('movie-genre', 'movie', array(
  'hierarchical'    => true,
  'label'           => 'Genre',
  'query_var'       => 'movie-genre',
  'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'genres' ),
));
```

Note I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question but won't mark it as best unless nobody else steps up with a really good answer too. Also my gut feeling tells me I might not have capture every distinction between the two dichotomies so if not please let us know what I missed.

Comment: Can you also explain what is hierarchical to what? Is the taxonomy-group hierarchical to the post type? Or is the individual taxonomy hierarchical to the taxonomy-group? I'm just thrown off by the word hierarchical I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The **simple answer** is that *terms in hierarchical taxonomies can have **child terms***. But what else?

### 'hierarchical'=>false

When you specify a `'hierarchical'=>false` you get the following type of metabox which is the metabox format WordPress also uses for *Post Tags*:

[image: Taxonomy Term Metabox in the Post Edit Screen when $hierarchical==false]

### 'hierarchical'=>true

However when you specify `'hierarchical'=>true` you get the following type of metabox which is the metabox format WordPress also uses for *Categories*:

[image: Taxonomy Term Metabox in the Post Edit Screen when $hierarchical==true]

Of course the example above also points out where hierarchical categorization can be a bit of a mixed bag because in real life subcategories often apply to many parent categories. Even so alowing *"many parents"* is not how hierarchical taxonomies works in WordPress but IMO categorizing anything perfectly is almost impossible *regardless* of how WordPress works. So *Caveat Emptor!*

### On Custom Taxonomy Registration, or *"Why Won't it Save?"*

While not directly related to the question if you are a newbie trying out custom taxonomies, (*or an experienced dev who isn't paying attention like happened to me when I wrote this up!*) it's likely that you'll try adding `register_taxonomy()` like the code you see in the question directly into your theme's `functions.php` file. Oops!

If you do add the code directly into `functions.php` your metabox will display but it won't save your newly added terms (and in the `'heirarchical'=>true` form of the metabox your existing terms won't load with checkboxes.) That's because you need to register custom taxonomies (and custom post types) inside an `init` hook, like so:

```
<?php
add_action('init','register_movie_genre_taxonomy');
  function register_movie_genre_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy('movie-genre', 'movie', array(
      'hierarchical'    => true,
      'label'           => 'Movie Genre',
      'query_var'       => 'movie-genre',
      'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'genres' ),
    ));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is a Hierarchical Taxonomy the same thing as a custom category? And is a Non-Hierarchical Taxonomy the same thing as a custom tag?

Comment: @ravensfan55222 - Not exactly, but almost. Instead of a 'hierarchical taxonomy' being the same as a custom category, the built-in Category classification system is just one of many potential hierarchical taxonomies. Similarly (Post) Tags are just one example of a non-hierarchical taxonomy. More correctly, "hierarchical" is just an attribute of a taxonomy, like how a label is an just attribute of a taxonomy or color is an attribute of a car.  That might have been what you meant but I wanted to clarify if not.