# Show list of custom taxonomies when another taxonomy is selected

Tags: taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

Hard question to explain here. So here goes:

I have a chapter/section scenario I'm trying to work out. The custom post type of "Books" has two custom taxonomies, "Chapters" and "Sections". The Chapters, are sort of like the higher level taxonomy with Sections being inside each chapter. So it would look something like this:

- Chapter 1

  - Section 1.1
  - Section 1.2
  - Section 1.3
  - Section 1.4
- Chapter 2

  - Section 1.1
  - Section 1.2

Basically, I'm trying to list out the sections, relative to the specific Chapter on a Chapter taxonomy page. I'm using `get_terms()` to grab the list of section taxonomies. The problem is, when I use `get_terms()` it lists out every section in all Chapters. So for instance, Chapter 2 only has posts with Sections 1.1 and 1.2 selected. But using `get_terms()` lists out Sections 1.3 and 1.4 as well for that Chapter.

I need a way to isolate the sections taxonomy list to only those taxonomies which are selected in conjunction with the selected Chapter taxonomy.

In a way, it's sort of like this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50112/show-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-items-based-on-a-selected-item-from-another-custo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make more sense for the sections to be child terms below each chapter.  See [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50974/251) to the similar question you referenced as well as MikeSchinkel's [explanation of hierarchical taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/692/251).

Using the the term_id returned from get_terms use [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to get the sections associated with each chapter.